# Oracle Date Conversion

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a query field in MS access 2010 which will convert the Date for Asia Pacific Region.

My query field looks like this.This is a Calculated field. 'Employee List' is the Table Name and 'Region'&'Created' are the field Names here.Here 0.3958 is added to align the date of APAC region with remaining two other regions.

Report date:

```
CDate(Int(IIf([Employee List]![Region]="APAC",[Manual_list]![Created]+0.3958,[Manual_list]![Created])))
```

Now i am trying to achieve this result in Oracle but i am not that familiar in SQL. Could any one help me to have this result in oracle.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that adding `.3958` to a date in Access adds 9.5 hours (.3958 * 24 is approximately 9.5), the way to add 9.5 hours in Oracle is:

```
your_date + INTERVAL '570' MINUTE
```

That's because 9.5 hours = 570 minutes. You can also do this, which might read better; your choice:

```
your_date + INTERVAL '9' HOUR + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
```

To add the `IF` logic, use the [CASE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions004.htm) statement. Putting it all together, you get something like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN Region = 'APAC' THEN Created + INTERVAL '570' MINUTE
    ELSE Created
  END
FROM your_table
... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

In ORACLE, you can alter the timezone of the database:

```
ALTER database SET TIME_ZONE = '09:30';
```